# Numpy unique with expected unique values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to process the results of a numpy.unique calculation based on an expected set of unique values - the code below demonstrates what I want. Essentially, I want to have values of 0 when an expected unique value is not found.

```
import numpy

unqVals = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,6,6]
y = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
z = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5]

for cur in [x,y,z]:
    xx = numpy.unique(cur, return_counts=True)
    print xx[1]

''' Current Results
[3 3 2 2 2]
[2 2 2 2 2 2]
[2 3 4 2 1]

Desired Results - based on the unqVals definition 
[3 3 2 2 0 2]
[2 2 2 2 2 2]
[2 3 4 2 1 0]
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work -

```
from collections import Counter

unqVals = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,6,6]
y = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
z = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5]

for cur in [x,y,z]:
    xx = dict(Counter(cur))
    print [xx.get(i, 0) for i in unqVals ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That works really well, and is really fast!